# Can't connect to MySql Server and can't reconfigure MySql server

Tags: mysql

I had problem with connection to database in my Rails application, so reinstalled everything according to [this tutorial](https://docs.google.com/document/edit?id=1I0vg_xntIykSsfnorCLaYtDXS0OVulz3UH4eCouoKtg), and it doesn't help.

Now when I'm running the installation of MySql Server it says:

> error 1045 Access denied for 'root@localhost'(using password NO)

When I was reconfiguring leaved the field old password empty.
How I can solve this ?
Here is my log:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
>
> Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"testapp_development", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>"root", "host"=>"localhost"}, charset: , collation: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
>
> Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"mysql2", "encoding"=>"utf8", "reconnect"=>false, "database"=>"testapp_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"root", "password"=>nil, "host"=>"localhost"}, charset: , collation:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you left your password empty when you installed MySQL? But your Rails seems to be trying to connect with the password 'root'. Which is it? If your MySQL has a password, you need to use it to connect, and if it doesn't, you mustn't send one.

Comment: I've tried to leave blank password in database.yaml and it didn't help. I think it's trouble in reconfiguration. How I can delete ALL from last MySQL, I uninstall it and deleted folder MySQL, but when I installing and configuring again, it says, that it is already configured and gives me error

Answer (score 0):

hi same situation is here with me but it can be sought out by Services you just have to restart MySQL option again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).